# What ways to disable distracting animations on web sites?

Tags: browser, hci

When you're trying to access some information on the web, but the site has some glossy feature (Animated GIFs, Flash, etc. e.g.) that distracts from just concentrating on it's content, e.g. [www.london.gov.uk](http://www.london.gov.uk/). How to turn this "feature" off?

By the way I'm using IE7 + [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/), and already assigning some sites the IP 0.0.0.0 in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: It seems that you dont't undestand the difference between a web site and an IP address. Not to mention that Windows was caught ignoring some entries in its hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the URL of the site to IE > Tools > Internet Options > Security > Restricted sites

Answer (score 3):

You can give [AdBlock IE](http://adblockie.codeplex.com/) a try. Primarily to block advertising banners.

Comment: Does it block the animation on www.london.gov.uk?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Firefox with Adblock and NoScript add-ons.

It works like a charm and makes your browser more secure to XSS and other browser based attacks.

For IE just try Adblock and try disabling the scripts from the IE 7 settings.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trusty old **[Proxomitron](http://www.proxomitron.info/)**, a highly configurable global web filter that works for any browser.

[Here](http://sidki.proxfilter.net/prox.html) you'll find up-to-date config files that get your started with Proxomitron.